# Can't find where to add UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController in a NavigationController and one of the ViewControllers presented by the UIPageViewController needs to be able to add a 'Save' button to the navigation bar.

The problem is that I can't find any access to the navigation bar, so I set a break point and began digging for it and I can't seem to find where there is any access to the NavigationController or it's properties.

This is what I found:

```
(lldb) po self.toolbarItems
    $9 = 0x00000000 <nil>

(lldb) po self.parentViewController
    $10 = 0x1e070bc0 <UIPageViewController: 0x1e070bc0>

(lldb) po self.parentViewController.toolbarItems
    $11 = 0x00000000 <nil>

(lldb) po self.parentViewController.navigationController
    $12 = 0x00000000 <nil>

(lldb) po self.parentViewController.view
    $13 = 0x1d585960 <_UIPageViewControllerContentView: 0x1d585960; frame = (0 0; 320 
    416); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 
    0x1d5a1090>>

(lldb) po self.parentViewController.view.window
    $14 = 0x1e073750 <UIWindow: 0x1e073750; frame = (0 0; 320 480); layer = 
    <UIWindowLayer: 0x1e0756a0>>

(lldb) po self.parentViewController.view.window.rootViewController
    error: property 'rootViewController' not found on object of type 'id'
    error: 1 errors parsing expression

(lldb) po self.presentingViewController
    $15 = 0x00000000 <nil>
```

I've tried setting my rightBarButtonItem in my VC as well as the parent VC and even tried going to the topViewController and the rootViewController.

Can anyone offer any other suggestions as to where I might be able to get access to the NavigationController?

Comment: The only right way is `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = ...`. If it does not work for you then ensure that your VC is in NavigationController hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks Mark, but the tricky part is that my UIPageViewController is in the hierarchy and it is loading the VC that I need the save button for. So technically my VC is out of the hierarchy, but it's loaded by something that isn't. I may have to put the button somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put this in the UIViewController subclass

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.parentViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = ...
}
```

The only problem with that solution is Apple can change the UIPageViewController implementation at anytime to have more levels of view controller containment. The safer solution is this:

In the UIViewController subclass **.h** add:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIPageViewController *pageViewController;
```

in **.m** add:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    _pageViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = ...
}
```

and then don't forget to assign the pageViewController to the property in the appropriate location

```
myViewController.pageViewController = myPageViewController;
```

You could reset the UIPageViewController navigationItem's properties in the UIPageViewControllerDelegate Methods like this:

```
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed {
    if (completed) {
        UIViewController *viewController = [pageViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
        if (![viewController isKindOfClass:[CustomBarButtonItemViewController class]]) {
            pageViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this answer, and I'm sure it will work but I don't really want the button there for every page of the UIPageViewController, so I'm looking for a way to add it and remove it depending on the page being displayed. Unless it isn't possible to modify the NavBar once it's loaded, but I believe it is.

Comment: Well, although this isn't exactly the answer I was looking for, it's the best solution. I think adding a protocol to enable/disable the button from the UIPageViewController is probably how this is going to have to be done.  Thanks for the help Nick!

Comment: I edited my answer to solve your other requirement. You could do that or just override 'viewWillAppear' in your other UIViewController subclasses and set rightBarButtonItem to nil to remove the button.

Comment: Nice! I like that and it's a good place to put it too.  Thanks for the update Nick!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with another maybe more reliable approach than parentViewController.

As it seems nested UIViewControllers in e.g. the UIPageViewController could not directly contribute its UIBarButtonItem items via

```
self.navigationItem
```

just the direct child of the UINavigationController can do that.

But the nested UIViewControllers can access the UINavigationController via

```
self.navigationController
```

At least in viewWillAppear / viewDidAppear - unfortunately nil in viewDidLoad.

The topmost UIViewController in the UINavigationController is definitely somehow in the parentViewController hierarchy of the nested UIViewController.

So instead of stepping to (maybe more) parentViewControllers using the topmost UIViewController of the UINavigationController to set the navigationItems:

```
[[[self.navigationController.viewControllers lastObject] navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:barButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you create a method to get the navigationItem like the one bellow. It will always work wherever your pageViewController is.

```
- (UINavigationItem*) getNavigationItem{
UIViewController* viewController = self;
do
{
    if ([viewController.parentViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
        return viewController.navigationItem;

    viewController = viewController.parentViewController;
}
while (viewController.parentViewController);

return nil;
```

}

Than you can use it this way:

```
[self getNavigationItem].rightBarButtonItem = ...
```